# Installing Bika LIMS on Plone 5.0

Tags: plone

I am trying to install Plone in Ubuntu LTS 14 (newly built server) with Bika with the procedure here:
https://github.com/bikalabs/Bika-LIMS/blob/0c606e0/INSTALL.rst

I can start the Plone server using the command:

```
sudo -u plone_daemon bin/plonectl zeoserver start
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster# sudo -u plone_daemon bin/plonectl restart zeoserver
zeoserver: .
daemon process started, pid=3864
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster# sudo -u plone_daemon bin/plonectl status zeoserver
zeoserver: program running; pid=3864
```

But when I start the client1, it shows

> ERROR Application Could not import Products.ATExtensions':
>
> sudo -u plone_daemon bin/plonectl client1 fg
>
> The client1 could not be started.

Could you please help advise what the possible cause could be?

Here are the error messages while starting the client1:

```
/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster# sudo -u plone_daemon bin/plonectl fg client1
client1: 2015-10-11 12:37:05 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Oct 11 12:37:05 2015
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0
        Port: 8080
2015-10-11 12:37:07 ERROR Application Could not import Products.ATExtensions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 606, in import_product
    product=__import__(pname, global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ATExtensions-1.1-py2.7.egg/Products/ATExtensions/__init__.py", line 18, in module
    validation.register(PartialUrlValidator('isPartialUrl'))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.validation-2.0-py2.7.egg/Products/validation/service.py", line 33, in register
    raise FalseValidatorError, validator
FalseValidatorError: <Products.ATExtensions.validator.isPartialUrl.PartialUrlValidator instance at 0x7fe90f0048c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/parts/client1/bin/interpreter", line 302, in module
    exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in module
    run()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 86, in prepare
    self.startZope()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 262, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
    _startup()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 67, in startup
    OFS.Application.import_products()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 583, in import_products
    import_product(product_dir, product_name, raise_exc=debug_mode)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 606, in import_product
    product=__import__(pname, global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ATExtensions-1.1-py2.7.egg/Products/ATExtensions/__init__.py", line 18, in module
    validation.register(PartialUrlValidator('isPartialUrl'))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.validation-2.0-py2.7.egg/Products/validation/service.py", line 33, in register
    raise FalseValidatorError, validator
Products.validation.exceptions.FalseValidatorError: <Products.ATExtensions.validator.isPartialUrl.PartialUrlValidator instance at 0x7fe90f0048c0>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues and marked up the error message using >

Comment: Is that Plone 5 or Plone 4? (I wouldn't be surprised if nobody tested Archetypes against Plone5 anymore.)

Comment: I see that the traceback is referring to Products.ATExtensions, which is quite old and probably unmaitained. I think that nobody used it on Plone 5

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is Plone 5. We built the Unbuntu few days ago, under VMware ESXi 5. Played around the Bika.LIMS, and noticed the Client1 runs fine when I removed bika.lims from the eggs.

Answer (score 1):

Bika LIMS will not work out of the box in Plone 5, as it depends on [Products.ATExtensions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ATExtensions) and this package seems not to be compatible with Plone 5.

Besides that, Archetypes is not installed by default on Plone 5.